# Write into CSV file stored in IBM cloud object storage using IBM cloud function

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-storage

I have to read a CSV file stored in IBM cloud object through IBM cloud function which I did using Nodejs. Now I have to apply any logic to that file and write it back through IBM cloud function.

How can I do that (code please)?

Underlining is the code to read CSV file from IBM cloud object storage using 'Read-file' action in the IBM Cloud function.

const COS = require('ibm-cos-sdk').S3;

async function main(params) {

const IAM_API_KEY = process.env['__OW_IAM_NAMESPACE_API_KEY']

const ENDPOINT = 's3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'

const BUCKET = 'my-bucket'

const FILE = 'Sample.csv'

const config = {

```
 endpoint: ENDPOINT,

 apiKeyId: IAM_API_KEY
```

}

const cos = new COS(config);

const options = {   Bucket: BUCKET
   }

async function getItem(bucketName, itemName) {

console.log(`Retrieving item from bucket: ${bucketName}, key: ${itemName}`);

```
try{
    const data = await cos.getObject({
    Bucket: bucketName, 
    Key: itemName
}).promise()

    if (data != null) {

        console.log('File Contents: ' + Buffer.from(data.Body).toString())
        console.log("hellllllo");

    }    
     return data
}
catch(e){
    console.error(`ERROR: ${e.code} - ${e.message}\n`)
}
```

}

console.log(await getItem(BUCKET,FILE))

}

Comment: please help as soon as possible

Comment: please kindlyhelp